# Unable to install extensions - Joomla

Tags: extension, installation

Trying to install the summary fields extension, however I keep getting this odd error that I've been unable to figure out. Looks like this:

`An error has occurred.
 CiviCRM-001   @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css);    Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. Unknown extension: net.ourpowerbase.sumfields Return to home page.    function toggle( element ) { var className = element.className; if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') { element.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else { element.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } }`

I've tried to install on multiple occasions, however I get this same error. And, actually, I receive this error for any extension I attempt to install. Any ideas?